# Unable to display Google map in android's google map activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am creating a simple android application where I want to display google maps so I used the google map's activity but when I am running the application on my device, I am getting a blank screen with Google written at the bottom left .
I have used correct API Key. This is the Logcat. I am also not able to find the
the "Google Maps Android API v2" in the Google Developer Console . There is only 
Google Maps Android API which I have already enabled.

```
  Authentication failed on the server.
    09-18 16:38:47.158    2315-2451/? E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
    09-18 16:38:47.163    2315-2451/? E/Google Maps Android API﹕ In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
        Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
        Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
        API Key: AIzaSyA2PEin-GiKaerDpnoStcvKGmCmHJ2cZuI
        Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 85:84:5C:61:4D:15:26:5C:52:78:1F:86:9D:46:5A:C6:45:29:D1:B8;com.example.mapDemo
    09-18 16:38:49.438    5639-5639/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (10) POSIX Error : 11 SQLite Error : 3850
    09-18 16:39:00.123  30704-30704/? E/[AccuTab]﹕ {[87A192EF54E76DF503A22F31216BFA0960788D40C82B44EE1702A58D5517331C]}
    09-18 16:39:00.123  30704-30704/? E/[AccuTab]﹕ {[5CD3AD49228511B775B4B89D43787C6921CE939C82941DF49B0235A31366AD0C155EAD47CE71200FB8BACB33B4B42DF281207C3087E99E0EA192762118CD2EC2]}
    09-18 16:39:13.708    3350-5382/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 391 [09-18 16:39:13.708]
    09-18 16:39:29.883    5639-5639/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (10) POSIX Error : 11 SQLite Error : 3850
    09-18 16:39:43.708    3350-5382/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 392 [09-18 16:39:43.710]
    09-18 16:40:00.168  30704-30704/? E/[AccuTab]﹕ {[87A192EF54E76DF503A22F31216BFA09C9D803FB806A4AFA63BAF57FE025AD59]}
    09-18 16:40:00.173  30704-30704/? E/[AccuTab]﹕ {[5CD3AD49228511B775B4B89D43787C6921CE939C82941DF49B0235A31366AD0C155EAD47CE71200FB8BACB33B4B42DF281207C3087E99E0EA192762118CD2EC2]}
    09-18 16:40:13.708    3350-5382/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 393 [09-18 16:40:13.712]
    09-18 16:40:43.713    3350-5382/? E/Watchdog﹕ !@Sync 394 [09-18 16:40:43.714]
    09-18 16:40:51.918    5639-5639/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (10) POSIX Error : 11 SQLite Error : 3850
    09-18 16:40:56.393    3350-5676/? W/ActivityManager﹕ ProcessRecord{a6c6e91 30584:com.google.android.youtube/u0a150} is already killed
    09-18 16:40:56.398    2649-2649/? E/lowmemorykiller﹕ Error writing /proc/30584/oom_score_adj; errno=22
    09-18 16:40:56.398    3350-5676/? E/JavaBinder﹕ !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

This is the Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapDemo" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchResultActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_result" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image: This is the what I am getting]

I have also given the api key in the google maps key.
[image]

[image]

Comment: i have re-checked both ApI key and Google Map Android API and both are in correct way but stil I am not able to see the map on the screen.

Comment: where is your   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />   code in manifest

Comment: min or max version of sdk where is available declare min and max versions or Api level so that ADB can understand and assign map to device   ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for many hours I got to know that I moved my `.android` folder from `C: drive` to `D: drive` and have set the `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` with the new path but I didn't delete the previous folder. I was using the previous path to get the `Certificate fingerprints: Md5 ,SHA1` which were not correct. This was the only mitake that I made which is why the Sha1 was not matching.

Earlier I was using this

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\.android\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

to get the Certificate fingerprints but now I am using the correct path

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "D:\.android\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Had to follow the same procedure again on `console.developers.google.com` to get the API key and now I am able to get the map on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable "Google Maps Android API v2" api on google developer console and whatever your Android key (API Key: AIzaSyA2PEin-GiKaerDpnoStcvKGmCmHJ2cZuI) generated on google console, you should put this on manifest file.

Comment: its already there as android:value="@string/google_maps_key".

Comment: i didn't find Google Maps Android API v2 on developer console

Comment: go to Apis (right side of screen) on google console and enable Google Maps Android API

Comment: add this also in manifest file <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.bobbie.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.bobbie.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

Comment: these permissions are not required as per new guidelines. i have also tested them right now but no change